# Annihilator Method Help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble on some annihilator method problems for homework and was wondering if anyone would be able to point me in the right direction. The problem is:

$$y''-8y'+20y=5xe^{4x} \sin(2x)$$

I need to find the annihilator (I think it's actually the same as the left side, $(D^2-8D+20)^2$, though I could be wrong) and find the particular solution.

I understand how to do variation of parameters and undetermined coefficients but I need to learn how to do this problem the annihilator way. It's confusing me though. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the annihilator equation
$$ ((D-4)^2+4)^2(D^2-8D+20)y=0 $$
The corresponding characteristic equation is
$$ ((r-4)^2+4)^2(r^2-8r+20)=0 \text{ or }((r-4)^2+4)^3=0 $$
which has roots $r=4\pm 2i$
with multiplicity 3. Thus a general solution of the annihilator is
$$ y_a=(c_1+c_2x+c_3x^2)e^{(4+2i)x}+(c_4+c_5x+c_6x^2)e^{(4-2i)x}. $$
I think now you solve it.

Comment: That's exactly what I got. Thanks for helping!